# Kotlin exclude ktlint directories in maven

Tags: maven, kotlin

I am trying to remove generate-sources directory from giving klint errors, else adding a few scripts in exclude as an alternative

From here I figured we could do this in gradle
https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/issues/97

This feature in gradle is shown as follows

```
ktlint {
    filter {
        exclude("**/generated/**")
        include("**/kotlin/**")
    }
}
```

So far I have tried doing this in Maven, but it still does linting on some unavoidable generated sources.
https://github.com/gantsign/ktlint-maven-plugin/issues/341

```
<sourcesExcludes>
   <sourcesExcludes>directoryToExclude<sourcesExclude>
</sourcesExcludes>
```

Using above in maven plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.gantsign.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>ktlint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <configuration>
          <sourcesExcludes>
              <sourcesExclude>**/generated-sources/graphql/com/expediagroup/dataquality/api/utils/**</sourcesExclude>
          </sourcesExcludes>
      </configuration>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>format</goal>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any help on how I can exclude generated-sources directory is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here
https://github.com/gantsign/ktlint-maven-plugin/issues/341

And we just have to use below to avoid target files.

```
<configuration>
    <sourceRoots>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceRoots>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Developers did [a guide](https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/latest/install/integrations/) to set up Maven to use ant-task:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>ktlint</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <configuration>
        <target name="ktlint">
            <java taskname="ktlint" dir="${basedir}" fork="true" failonerror="true"
                classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" classname="com.pinterest.ktlint.Main">
              <!-- Note: the JVM arg below is only required when running ktlint with Java 16+ in format mode.
              <jvmarg value="--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"/>
              -->
              <!-- see https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/install/cli/#command-line-usage for more information -->
              <arg value="src/**/*.kt"/>
            </java>
        </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>ktlint-format</id>
        <configuration>
        <target name="ktlint">
            <java taskname="ktlint" dir="${basedir}" fork="true" failonerror="true"
                classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" classname="com.pinterest.ktlint.Main">
                <!-- Note: the JVM args below is only required when running ktlint with Java 16+ in format mode -->
                <jvmarg value="--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"/>
                <!-- see https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/install/cli/#command-line-usage for more information -->
                <arg value="-F"/>
                <arg value="src/**/*.kt"/>
            </java>
        </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pinterest.ktlint</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktlint-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- additional 3rd party ruleset(s) can be specified here -->
</dependencies>
```

I've copied in case urls changed. Here you could add an argument like:

```
<arg value="!**/generated/**"/>
```

And `ktlint` will skip the directory. Works in latest version at least.